# Having The "Camera" positioning On The Player in Java

Tags: java, slick2d

So I've been having some trouble with positioning the "camera" on the player since this is my first time trying to accomplish this. Whenever I launch my game and I move my player, the camera doesn't seem to center on the player like I hope it to do and I don't know what is wrong with it. I've tried looking through online resources and checked out many questions on stack overflow but I could not find what I did wrong :/ . I am using Java and using the Slick2D engine. Here are my class files:

Camera.class:

```
private float offsetMaxX;
private float offsetMaxY;
private float offsetMinX = 0;
private float offsetMinY = 0;
public float camX;
public float camY;

public Camera () {
    super ();
}

public void update (float playerX, float playerY, float mapX, float mapY){
    offsetMaxX = mapX - Main.WIDTH;
    offsetMaxY = mapY - Main.HEIGHT;

    camX = playerX - Main.WIDTH/2;
    camY = playerY - Main.HEIGHT/2;

    if (camX > offsetMaxX) {
        camX = offsetMaxX;
    } else if (camX < offsetMinX) {
        camX = offsetMinX;
    }
    if (camY > offsetMaxY) {
        camY = offsetMaxY;
    } else if (camY < offsetMinY) {
        camY = offsetMinY;
    }
}

public float getCamX() {
    return camX;
}

public float getCamY() {
    return camY;
}

public float getOffsetMaxX() {
    return offsetMaxX;
}

public float getOffsetMaxY() {
    return offsetMaxY;
}

public float getOffsetMinX() {
    return offsetMinX;
}

public float getOffsetMinY() {
    return offsetMinY;
}

public void setOffsetMaxX(float offsetMaxX) {
    this.offsetMaxX = offsetMaxX;
}

public void setOffsetMaxY(float offsetMaxY) {
    this.offsetMaxY = offsetMaxY;
}

public void setOffsetMinX(float offsetMinX) {
    this.offsetMinX = offsetMinX;
}

public void setOffsetMinY(float offsetMinY) {
    this.offsetMinY = offsetMinY;
}
```

And my Game.class:

```
// Player variables
public SpriteSheet playerSS = null;
protected InputHandler inputHandler;
public float playerX = Main.WIDTH/2, playerY = Main.HEIGHT/2;
private Animation sprite, runningAnimationLEFT, runningAnimationRIGHT, runningAnimationUP, runningAnimationDOWN;
private Animation standLEFT, standRIGHT, standUP, standDOWN; //THIS IS TO PREVENT ANIMATIONS FROM CONTINUING AFTER THE PLAYER STOPS
private int duration = 300;
public boolean isMoving, isLeft, isRight, isUp, isDown;


//Map
private Image testMap; //This is a test map
private float mapX = 1024, mapY = 1024;

//Camera
public Camera camera;

public Game (int stateID) {}

@Override
public int getID() {
    return Main.game; //GAMESTATE = 1
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame) throws SlickException {
    playerSS = new SpriteSheet("res/characters/player_sprite_sheet.png", 50, 75);
    testMap = new Image ("res/grassMap.png");
    camera = new Camera();

    // ANIMATIONS
    runningAnimationDOWN = new Animation();
    runningAnimationDOWN.setAutoUpdate(true);
    runningAnimationDOWN.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 0), duration);
    runningAnimationDOWN.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(0, 0), duration);
    runningAnimationDOWN.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(2, 0), duration);

    runningAnimationLEFT = new Animation();
    runningAnimationLEFT.setAutoUpdate(true);
    runningAnimationLEFT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 1), duration);
    runningAnimationLEFT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(0, 1), duration);
    runningAnimationLEFT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(2, 1), duration);

    runningAnimationRIGHT = new Animation();
    runningAnimationRIGHT.setAutoUpdate(true);
    runningAnimationRIGHT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 2), duration);
    runningAnimationRIGHT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(0, 2), duration);
    runningAnimationRIGHT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(2, 2), duration);

    runningAnimationUP = new Animation();
    runningAnimationUP.setAutoUpdate(true);
    runningAnimationUP.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 3), duration);
    runningAnimationUP.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(0, 3), duration);
    runningAnimationUP.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(2, 3), duration);

    standDOWN = new Animation();
    standDOWN.setAutoUpdate(true);
    standDOWN.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 0), duration);

    standLEFT = new Animation();
    standLEFT.setAutoUpdate(true);
    standLEFT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 1), duration);

    standRIGHT = new Animation();
    standRIGHT.setAutoUpdate(true);
    standRIGHT.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 2), duration);

    standUP = new Animation();
    standUP.setAutoUpdate(true);
    standUP.addFrame(playerSS.getSprite(1, 3), duration);

    sprite = standDOWN;
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame, int delta) throws SlickException {
    inputHandler.updateKeyboardRelay(gameContainer);
    isMoving = false;

    if (inputHandler.keyUP) {
        isUp = true;
        isDown = false;
        isLeft = false;
        isRight = false;
        isMoving = true;
        playerY -= delta * 0.1f;
    } else if (inputHandler.keyDOWN) {
        isDown = true;
        isUp = false;
        isLeft = false;
        isRight = false;
        isMoving = true;
        playerY += delta * 0.1f;
    } else if (inputHandler.keyLEFT) {
        isLeft = true;
        isUp = false;
        isDown = false;
        isRight = false;
        isMoving = true;
        playerX -= delta * 0.1f;
    } else if (inputHandler.keyRIGHT) {
        isRight = true;
        isUp = false;
        isDown = false;
        isLeft = false;
        isMoving = true;
        playerX += delta * 0.1f;
    }

    if (isMoving) {
        if (inputHandler.keyUP) {
            sprite = runningAnimationUP;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (inputHandler.keyDOWN) {
            sprite = runningAnimationDOWN;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (inputHandler.keyLEFT) {
            sprite = runningAnimationLEFT;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (inputHandler.keyRIGHT) {
            sprite = runningAnimationRIGHT;
            sprite.update(delta);
        }
    } else {
        if (isDown) {
            sprite = standDOWN;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (isUp) {
            sprite = standUP;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (isLeft) {
            sprite = standLEFT;
            sprite.update(delta);
        } else if (isRight) {
            sprite = standRIGHT;
            sprite.update(delta);
        }
    }

    // Map Boundaries
    if (playerX > mapX) {
        playerX = mapX;
    } else if (playerX < 0) {
        playerX = 0;
    }
    if (playerY > mapY) {
        playerY = mapY;
    } else if (playerY < 0) {
        playerY = 0;
    }

    camera.update(playerX, playerY, mapX, mapY);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame, Graphics graphics) throws SlickException {
    testMap.draw(mapX - 1024, mapY - 1024);

    graphics.translate(camera.getCamX(), camera.getCamY());
    sprite.draw(playerX, playerY);
    graphics.translate(-camera.getCamX(), -camera.getCamY());

    graphics.drawString("Player X: " + playerX, 400, 400);
    graphics.drawString("Player Y: " + playerY, 400, 415);

}
```

I feel like there is something specifically wrong in my Camera.class and my update(...) & render(...) methods, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your camera class in the update method try changing

```
camX = playerX - Main.WIDTH/2;
camY = playerY - Main.HEIGHT/2;
```

to

```
camX = playerX;
camY = playerY;
```

tell me if this does not work.

Comment: I did what you said, and the result I got was that the player went off the screen. So yes, it does not work.

Comment: Output the camX and camY values into the console and see if they are changing as the player moves.  @BlueJet

Comment: I just did that and it looks like their both outputting 0.0 in the console if I did it the way I have it in my code, but if I do it like camX = playerX etc. I get an output of 64 for x and 300 for y and the camY value changes as the player moves but the x value stays the same for some reason.

Comment: now output the position of the player and see if the cam positions and the player positions are the same.

Comment: They aren't really the same(camX = -100, playerX = 644 when camY = -100, playerY = 374).

Comment: Why are you using translations?  That is not necessary. @BlueJet

Comment: They aren't necessary? Then what should I replace them with?

Comment: delete them alltogether

Comment: Alright I deleted them out, though now the player is catching up with the map whenever the player moves on the x and y axis.

Comment: I think I got the solution, I re-added the translations into the render method, but I also put the testMap.draw(...) inside of the translations and when I run the game the player is centered in the camera view and whenever the player moves the camera moves with it. I believe this is the solution but what you said has also helped out as well, so I'll be marking this correct. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thank you if you have anymore slick2d or java questions then just ask.